# "wallet" vs. "[change] purse" in NAmEng and BrEng vernaculars

Tags: word-usage, british-english, north-american-english, vernacular, gender-positive

Is a man's [**change purse**](http://www.polartcenter.com/Polish_Leather_Change_Purse_Portmonetka_Podkowka_p/9816979.htm) sometimes called ***wallet*** by their owner?

If so, what would they usually call their actual [**wallet**](https://pixabay.com/pt/carteira-cart%C3%B5es-de-pagamento-pagar-367975/) to distinguish it from their change purse?

> **purse**:
>
> a small bag, pouch, or case for carrying money: a change purse.
>
> **wallet** [Ngram wallet vs. billfold](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wallet%2Cbillfold&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwallet%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbillfold%3B%2Cc0):
>
> a flat, folding case with compartments for paper money and other items, as credit cards, driver's license, and sometimes coins, carried in a pocket or handbag. [Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wallet)

Comment: There is a difference between a "small pouch or case" for coins and a "folding case with a compartment for coins".

Comment: I would guess that "billfold" is more commonly used that "wallet" in the US, to denote a relatively flat folding case used for money and credit cards.  A few men may carry some sort of a "change purse" of a size that would fit in the palm of the hand, but most don't.  Otherwise "purse" is (almost) exclusively female -- the male version is somewhat humorously referred to as a "man bag".

Comment: Your edit has actually changed the question significantly.

Comment: I've never heard of somebody calling a *coin purse* a *wallet*. If you google, it appears that some people call it a *coin pouch*; I assume these are men who don't want to use the word *purse*.

Comment: @Hot Licks: where I live, I almost always hear *wallet* and not *billfold*. It must be a regional difference.

Comment: @PeterSnor Does "change/coin purse" have strong gender connotations in AmEng vernacular, or is the term commonly used by both genders?

Comment: The word *purse* definitely has a strong gender connotation. I suspect some men think this carries over to *coin purse*, while others don't. But I don't really know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm British and your definition 1 of *wallet* is what I understand it to mean.  *Wallet* is the only word I would use to describe such an item.  It would be rare for a man to carry both.  Either his wallet has a coin compartment (zipped) or he carries coins loose in his pocket.  In my case, both.

A purse, in my British English, is the woman's equivalent.  This is often slightly larger (too big for a pocket) and carried in a handbag, but even if it's pocket sized it would still be called a purse.

The typical usage is so gendered that the same small black leather item could easily be described as "her purse" or "his wallet". "His purse" wouldn't be used for a physical item; it sounds like an item from centuries ago, or a figurative use.  "Her wallet" would also seem uncommon.

A *coin purse* or *change purse* looks like what you get for [a google search on "coin purse"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=coin+purse) (no image inline as the variety is what I'm trying to show).

Your second definition of *wallet* (Brit: a small bag) is dated as a standalone word; *travel wallet* is sometimes used (mainly by manufacturers, but also if carried by someone who's also carrying something like a handbag).  It may be described as a man-bag if carried by a man.

Comment: Note, the definitions I refer to were present in the question when I wrote the answer.

Comment: For what it's worth- I'm American, and I concur.